# Вызов функции из другой функции java

Tags: java

Всем добрый день. Задание, подсчитать сумму введенных чисел в заданном диапазоне и среднее арифметическое. Все значения вывести на экран. У меня, первая функция делает подсчет суммы от заданного числа до заданного числа, вторая функция должна делать подсчет среднего арифметического значения, но у меня не получается. Нужно вызвать из второй функции первую функцию не используя передачи в функцию functionArithmeticalMean третьего аргумента. Подскажите как правильно?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    class Test
    {//найти сумму чисел в диапазоне от rangeBeginning до rangeEnd и среднее арифметическое
        public static int functionRangeOfNumbers(int rangeBeginning, int rangeEnd)
        {
            int rangeOfNumbers = 0;
            for (int i = rangeBeginning; i < rangeEnd; i++)
            {
                rangeOfNumbers += i;
            }
            return rangeOfNumbers;
        }
        public static int functionArithmeticalMean(int rangeBeginning, int rangeEnd)
        {
            return functionRangeOfNumbers(rangeBeginning, rangeEnd) / (rangeEnd / rangeBeginning + 1);
        }
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int rangeBeginning;
            int rangeEnd;
            int sumOfNumbers;
            int arithmeticalMean;
            System.out.println("Введите начальное число");
            rangeBeginning = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Введите конечное число");
            rangeEnd = sc.nextInt();
            sumOfNumbers = functionRangeOfNumbers(rangeBeginning, rangeEnd);//сумма чисел
            arithmeticalMean = functionArithmeticalMean(rangeBeginning, rangeEnd);//среднее арифметическое
            System.out.println("Сумма чисел " + sumOfNumbers);
            System.out.println("Среднее арифметическое " + arithmeticalMean);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Решение как всегда банально и просто. В место знака деление нужен знак минус и все получится! Возможно кому то пригодится. Не забудьте поставить в цикле for значение (<=)

```
public static int functionArithmeticalMean(int rangeBeginning, int rangeEnd)
    {
        return functionRangeOfNumbers(rangeBeginning, rangeEnd) / (rangeEnd - rangeBeginning + 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы тут не учитываете последний элемент, надо все-таки `<=`:

```
for (int i = rangeBeginning; i < rangeEnd; i++)
```

Вам, также, необходимо посчитать количество элементов в вашем диапозоне. Можно, например, сделать  глобальную переменную, и инкрементировать её в цикле в методе `functionRangeOfNumbers`.
Метод `functionArithmeticalMean` мне кажется излишний, т.к. ср. арифмитическое вы можете подсчитать `arithmeticalMean = sumOfNumbers / amount`, где `amount` это количество элементов в вашем диапозоне.